# Создание зависимостей, аннотация OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

между таблицами у меня связь один ко многим, использую аннотацию `@JoinColumn`, насколько понимаю при этой аннотации просто добавляется дополнительный столбик с идентификатором к одной из таблиц, но у меня создается дополнительная промежуточная таблица, хотел бы спросить почему.
Первая сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long TRANSACTION_ID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID") 
    private Account account;
```

Вторая сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long ACCOUNT_ID;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Использование аннотации `@JoinColumn` нужно для того, чтобы указать какой столбец таблицы будет использоваться при установке соединения `JOIN` в SQL запросе при выборке данных, помещаемых в данный объект. При отношениях `@OneToMany` и `@ManyToOne`,  промежуточная таблица не используется. А используются она в случае `@ManyToMany`  отношений. Если таблица не используется, то её можно спокойно удалить или перегенерить схему базы данных с помощью `hbm2ddl.auto=create`.